# Problema con herencia multi-tabla en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema implementando herencia multi-tabla en Django. En mi archivo models.py tengo el siguiente modelo que es el padre:

```
class Concepto(models.Model):
    id_concepto = models.IntegerField()
```

Y estos son sus hijos:

```
class Estructura(Concepto):
    estructura_padre = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Usuario(Concepto):
    estructura = models.ManyToManyField(Estructura)
```

Sin embargo definir la herencia de esta manera produce un error. Primeramente tengo que incluir el siguiente import en la clase models.py (donde vienen estos modelos):

```
from calendario.models import Concepto
```

Pero en los ejemplos de herencia multi-tabla que vienen en la documentacion de Django 1.11.1 (el que estoy usando) no tiene ese import, simplemente definen el modelo padre y luego el hijo:

```
from django.db import models

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Restaurant(Place):
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Como pueden apreciar en el ejemplo no tienen que importar el modelo padre.

**EDITADO**

Cuando trato de ejecutar el comando makemigrations obtengo el siguiente error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/calendario/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from calendario.models import Concepto
ImportError: cannot import name 'Concepto'
```

Como pueden apreciar, me da error en models.py cuando hago el import del modelo Concepto (el modelo padre) y me dice que no puede hacer ese import. Pueden decirme que estoy haciendo mal? Gracias de antemano.

**EDITADO**

A continuacion los dejo con la estructura del proyecto:

```
proyecto
    calendario
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py (aqui esta el modelo padre Concepto y los hijos Estructura y Usuario)
        serializers.py (tengo hecho un serializer para Concepto)
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py (aqui tengo algunas vistas que manejan Concepto por tanto tengo que importarlo)
```

Comment: El error te dice que no puede encontrar el modelo `Concepto` por lo que te sugiero que verifiques con exactitud donde se encuentra dicho modelo para importarlo de manera adecuada, es a primera linea que arroja el error es cuando dices `from calendario.views import Concepto`, cuando lo normal seria que esté en los modelos

Comment: Hola @GermanAlzate, he editado la salida del error y ahora muestra donde esta el problema, lo del views al parecer fue un error mio al copiar el codigo del error.

Comment: @Ethan Hola, ¿me muestras la estructura de tu proyecto? ¿cómo se llama el archivo en que está definido `Concepto`? ¿Está en un `app` instalada? Por cierto, ¿te has dado cuenta de que estás importando un archivo desde el mismo?

Comment: @yorodom Ya subi un ejemplo de la estructura, saludos

Comment: @Ethan Si tienes todos los modelos en el mismo archivo te sobra el `import`, cual era el error que te lanzaba antes de cambiaras eso?

Comment: @yorom Es verdad que ese import sobra, pero si no se lo pongo cuando trato de hacer un modelo hijo por ejemplo class Usuario(Concepto) obtengo el error Unresolved reference 'Concepto'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, acabo de descubir el error y realmente me siento muy tonto porque ha sido un error de principiante en Django. En fin, lo que sucede es que estaba declarando las clases hijas y posteriormente la clase padre, o sea:

```
class Estructura(Concepto):
    estructura_padre = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Usuario(Concepto):
    estructura = models.ManyToManyField(Estructura)

class Concepto(models.Model):
    id_concepto = models.IntegerField()
```

Teniendo presente esto, arregle el resto de mi archivo models.py y ahora todo funciona de maravillas.